# Condition on domain for existence of vector potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, vector-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be open. I would like to have a reference for something like

> Assume that $\Omega$ satisfies (*), then every solenoidal vector field possesses a vector potential, i.e., for every $F \in C^1(\Omega; \mathbb R^3)$ with $\operatorname{div}F = 0$, there exists $G \in C^2(\Omega; \mathbb R^3)$ such that $F = \operatorname{rot}G$.

Here, (*) should be as weak as possible.

For star-shaped domains, this is known as Poincaré's lemma. However, it should also hold for domains "without inner boundaries" (claimed [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Ehoughton/231/Notes/ChrisFord/vp.pdf)), but I am not able to find a reference for this stronger result.

Also clear: $\Omega$ being simply connected is not enough, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4272245.

Comment: If this translates into the language of differential forms the way I think it does, a necessary and sufficient condition is that second de Rham cohomology $H^2(U, \mathbb{R})$ vanishes. In particular it suffices for $U$ to be contractible, but really you only need $H_2$ to be torsion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought the de Rham theorem is for compact manifolds. Is the same true for open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Sergei: the de Rham theorem holds for all smooth manifolds; it’s stated this way on Wikipedia.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ok, thank you!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan still I don't understand something. Does the equality $H^2(U,\mathbb{R})=0$ in the non-compact case really mean what we expect it to mean (each closed suface must be a boundary of a compact domain, or something equivalent)? I think, I am reading wrong books, where is this written?

Comment: @Sergei: no, it doesn’t mean that. In de Rham conomology it means that every closed $2$-form is exact, and by the universal coefficient theorem it means that $\text{Hom}(H_2(U), \mathbb{R})$ vanishes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan by this variant of the de Rham theorem the vanishing of $\operatorname{Hom}(H^2(U),\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to $H^2(U,\mathbb{R})=0$, is it? But what does this mean in terms of properties of the manifold? If the manifold (in our case, $U$) is compact I used to think that this is exactly the statement that each closed surface in $U$ is a boundary of a compact domain in $U$ (or, better to say, a hypersurface of the dimension 3 in $U$). It this the same for non-compact manifolds $U$?

Comment: @Sergei: no, as I said, it doesn’t mean that. Setting aside the question of when homology classes can be represented by submanifolds, which I’m not an expert in, if $H_2(U)$ is finitely generated this condition only implies that it’s torsion, not that it vanishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a nice reference specifically for the three-dimensional situation:

> Cantarella, Jason; DeTurck, Dennis; Gluck, Herman (Mai 2002).
> „Vector Calculus and
> the Topology of Domains in 3-Space“.
> The American Mathematical Monthly
> 109.5, S. 409–442.
> doi: [10.1080/00029890.2002.11919870](https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2002.11919870).